# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{A-bx}e^{-x^2}dx$ and why integration by parts fail?

Tags: integration, integration-by-parts

Th following integral (A,B are constants)
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{A-bx}e^{-x^2}dx$$
pops up as a curve fitting routine

Attempt to integrate it by parts (setting $u=\sqrt{A-bx},v'=e^{x^2}$) gives

EDIT: In detail

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{A-bx}e^{-x^2}dx=\left[\sqrt{A-bx}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x'^2}dx'\right)\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-b}{2\sqrt{A-bx}}\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x'^2}dx'\right)dx$$

Note that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$. Therefore

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{A-bx}e^{-x^2}dx=\left[\sqrt{A-bx}\sqrt{\pi}\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{-b}{2\sqrt{A-bx}}\sqrt{\pi}dx$$

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{A-bx}e^{-x^2}dx=\left[\sqrt{A-bx}\sqrt{\pi}\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}+\left[\sqrt{A-bx}\sqrt{\pi}\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}$$

$$=2\sqrt{\pi}\left[\sqrt{A-bx}\right]^{\infty}_{-\infty}$$

which diverges

A brief read on a [related link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288692/int-infty-infty-frac-sinxx-dx-with-integration-by-parts) and the discussion with a user about how there is a branch in the $\sqrt{}$ function in $\mathbb{C}$ caused me to suspect whether it is because of the branch point in the squareroot function that lead to integration by parts to fail

> 1. Why does integration by parts fail, what is the source of the diverging term despite the integral is known to converge?
> 2. What is the correct way to integrate it, should I split it into two parts like so: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}=\int_{-\infty}^{0}+\int_{0}^{\infty}$?

Comment: If $x > A/b$, how do you propose to address the square root term's value?

Comment: How $\sqrt{A-bx}$ is defined when $bx>A$?

Comment: if term in $\sqrt{}$ is negative, then we will end up in the complex numbers?

But that does not really explain why a diverging term pop up in the integration by parts (because even if we consider complex numbers, '$\sqrt{-\infty}$' still diverges)

You can suppose the integral is evaluated in the complex plane, thus the answer is allowed to be complex

Comment: If you define $\sqrt{r}$ for $r<0$ as $i\sqrt{-r}$ the problem boils down to computing $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-(c x^{2/3}+d)^2\right)\,dx $ that can be done through Bessel K functions, $K_{1/4}$ and $K_{3/4}$.

Comment: I am not familar with the above type of integrals. Any sources or tables I can read about on learning how to compute them?

Comment: I don't know how you are able to get that term through using by parts. Where exactly does it show up in the calculation, because using by parts won't simplify the integrand at all.

Comment: @wgrenard I have edited the question to include the detailed workings on the diverging term showing up

Comment: @Secret: that term is not diverging, it is simply not defined in your question. You cannot ask for the integral of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ if $f(x)$ is not even defined on a sub-interval of $[a,b]$. Please state what is the intended meaning of $\sqrt{-300}$ and maybe we will be able to help you.

Comment: As mentioned above, we treat the domain and range of integrationto be the complex plane, thus all negative square roots will be imaginary taking the principle branch for example. So the question will boil down to the integral you suggest, which I don't know how to calculate, nor whether the problematic interval will be defined if we use complex numbers